# Python - Convert UTC datetime.timetz() to local time

Tags: python, datetime, time

Having a hard time searching for this since it's mostly datetime or similar-but-different results and still seeming to struggle with getting suggestions for slightly different problems to work with this one.

I have some UTC datetime object: `timestamp`. What I'm doing is dealing with many timestamps and corresponding values and bucketing them hour by hour, so I'm bucketing them by `timestamp.timetz()`.

Now I want to loop through these buckets, take this UTC time object, and convert it to Eastern time, e.g. I want `00:00` to become `20:00`, keeping daylight savings in mind.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "pytz" package to get this done. Below is a example to get current time using pytz in eastern timezone.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

est_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
datetime.now(est_tz)
```

Hope it helps.
Happy Coding !! :)